# Difference between === and ==

Tags: php, comparison, operators

So I just saw the examples of `strpos`...and wondered why they explicitely mentioned that they used three equal signs? I have always used two, but heared that three are better for numeric operations...i am confused.

So, what is the difference between **===** and **==** ?

Comment: The manual is a good place to start: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php.

Answer (score 0):

"===" also checks to make sure the variables are of the same type.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php